# C# mutex in release mode behaves different than in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, mutex, release

So I have the following code:

```
...
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file=DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString();
    File.AppendAllText(file, "Mutex\r\n");

    bool CreatedNew;
    Mutex mutex=new Mutex(true, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, out CreatedNew);

    if(CreatedNew)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        File.AppendAllText(file, "Launching in DEBUG mode\r\n");
        #else
        File.AppendAllText(file, "Launching in RELEASE mode\r\n");
        #endif

        //Program.Launch();
        Program.ProcessArgsAndLaunch(args);
    }
    else
    {
        File.AppendAllText(file, "Handling dupe\r\n");
        Program.HandleDuplicate();
    }
}
...
```

I've checked innumerable articles here and other sites with no luck.

Basically, the code checks for a running instance of the app and if there is one, it switches to the main window of the running one. If not, it launches the app.

In `Debug` mode it all works as expected, the problem starts when I switch my configuration to `Release`: the app always starts (with `Mutex` seemingly doing nothing).

I've added conditionally compiled dumps that show in which mode the app is starting and the output changes based on the configuration, but sadly, so does the behaviour of the app.

This may be a `race condition` but I am not sure.

More code will be posted if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Along with Juan's answer, there's a difference in terms of garbage collection between launching inside and outside a debugger. That's not quite the same as a Debug configuration vs a Release configuration, but it's something you should be aware of anyway.

In the debugger, a local variable will act as a GC root for its entire scope - but when you're not debugging, your `mutex` variable isn't a GC root at all, because you don't *use* it after initializing it. That means your `Mutex` can be garbage collected (and thus the native mutex will be released) pretty much immediately.

You should use a `using` statement to *explicitly* dispose the `Mutex` at the right time:

```
// Note that you don't need a variable here... you can have one if you
// want though
using (new Mutex(...))
{
    // Code here to be executed while holding the mutex
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, this was the issue. As soon as I placed my code into a `using` statement, it all worked. And you're right, I didn't need the variable...

Answer (score 8):

If you have one instance running as Debug and another as Release, they will not share the same mutex, because AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName is different dependening on whether the hosting process is active or not.

As seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear, I would compile under `Debug` or `Release`, then launch the newly compiled app from within `Explorer`. Then I would close (all) instance(s), clean solution, change configuration, then recompile, then launch (again, from `Windows Explorer`)...